# Extraer hashtags de un archivo .csv

Tags: python, regex

Tengo un archivo .csv con tweets relacionados con los Juegos Olímpicos de Tokio 2020. Necesito una función Python que tenga como entrada la ruta del archivo .csv y uno de los días como parámetro opcional (2021-07-24, como default).

La salida de la función debe ser una tupla(número de hashtags de ese día, y una lista de los hashtags de ese mismo día). Todo ello para cada uno de los días 24, 25, 26 y 27.

He intentado empezar, pero no sé por dónde salir.

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

tweet = pd.read_csv('./data/tokyo_2020_tweets.csv')


def get_hashtags(tweet, date='2021-07-24'):
    hashtags = re.findall(r"#(\w+)", tweet)
    return (hashtags)

get_hashtags
```

Comment: Hello Friend, your Post has a problem and is written in a different Language than the expected on the Site; I recommend that you translate it into Spanish.

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Me parece que a tu POST contiene código no formateado, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Esta en el espacio de Español, sería bueno que tradujeses la pregunta, para evitar que sea cerrada

Comment: Para empezar no estoy seguro de si tienes bien el parámetro del método `findall` puesto que no puede haber un espacio entre la "r" y "#(\w+)" o te dará error.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jose Rodriguez. Ese era un error tipográfico. Ahora, al ejecutar la celda, obtengo el siguiente código:'<function __main__.get_hashtags(tweet, date='2021-07-24')>'

Comment: Podrías publicar la solución que llevaste a cabo?